# pre-built environments/effects?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a question regarding a project.  I need advice on the quickest way to produce.  I have two boxers fighting in a green studio, and have them wearing two green sleeves (one each).  I put markers on them etc... is there such a thing as pre-built environments that in overlay onto green studio and arm effects for the sleeves?
OR what is the cheapest and most effective /place to hire

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Blender

Comment: I think you are looking for a [motion capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture) system, of which none are available that use blender. If your needs are simple, [motion tracking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/introduction.html) may suit your needs.